# Migrating web app from ArcGIS Online to ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online

I have a webapp built in ArcGIS Online using the available templates, I want to move it to ArcGIS Server, I cannot find Esri's 'official' way to do it.

Where can I find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/ and download the SDK. Running the statup.bat file, you can specify the ArcGIS online URL of your data, build the app locally, then can host on your own ArcGIS Server.

Comment: Will the app be copied entirely to ArcGIS Server automatically, or just the raw data the app is based on?

Comment: Once you configure the app you can download it. I believe it is all the web app related data. It only references the underlying data used in the webmap/app.

Comment: What about opening the arcgisonline maps in ArcGIS Desktop and then, Publish them as Services into ArcGIS Server using the tool, will it not be much easier?

Comment: you can try that as well, whichever solves your issue